# HTML5 input validate

Tags: html, validation

i want a HTML5 form validation pattern that can very strictly validate these characters...

```
IN16/20032/2012
in16/20032/12
inP12/20003/13
inP32/20003/2013
```

1. there must be **only two** back slashes
2. upper case and lower case aphabets are allowed **(maximum of 3, minimum of 2)**
3. number must not **be less than 9, or more than 11**
4. must start with alphabets
5. must not start with number

for example, the validation should reject the following:

```
ihfg45/......
```

`45in/........`etc, 
please assist me solve this and i will greately appreciate...
i vale looked at the following links...
**http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2012/11/21/html5-form-validation/** and
**http://w3resource.com/gallery/html5-based-fom-validation-without-javascript**

Comment: Are there always no more and no less than five numbers between the slashes?

Comment: hi Joseph, before the first back slash, there can be between 4-6 alphanumeric, after the first slash, there can only be only 5 numbers , and after the second slash, there can be between 2-4 numbers (only)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should cover your validation rules

```
(?:[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2,4}|[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1,3})\/[0-9]{5}\/[0-9]{2,4}
```

You can read the explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/gN1aD7/1 (Note that you don't need `^` and `$` for HTML5 validation.  It's implied).

And here is a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sb9agLtt/